# How to determine that there is no batch effect? Do these coins have the same P value?

Tags: r, python, lme4-nlme, binomial-distribution

I have some data that was gathered in several batches, and I want to determine if there is a statistically relevant difference in the results of each batch.

Edit: Clarification: I want to test the null hypothesis that each batch has the same p value.

To avoid having to go into the background of the experiment, here's a perfect analogy:

We have three coins and flip them a bunch.

Coin1: 75 heads, 25 tails.

Coin2: 73 heads, 27 tails.

Coin3: 80 heads, 20 tails.

They aren't fair coins; we're not worried about that right now. What I want to know is: with what degree of certainty can I say the coins are *equally* fair to one another?

I have been told that the way to go is to fit a binomial model to the data and the use that to determine if it is credible that there is no difference in the true underlying p-value. I have been recommended using either the R package brms or lme4 (though this is not strictly required). However, I am at a loss as to how to go about this. My experience with R is extremely limited, and I would use Python instead in a heartbeat.

Thus far, I have tried setting up the model in a few ways:

Note: I'm posting using miniturized data:
Coin1: 5 heads, 0 tails
Coin2: 4 heads, 1 tails.
Coin3: 3 heads, 2 tails.

```
Coin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Result = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
d <- data.frame(Coin , Result)
model <- glmer(Result ~ Coin + (1 | Coin), data = d, family = binomial, nAGQ = 10)
```

I've also tried `glmer(Result ~ 1 + (1 | Coin), data = d, family = binomial, nAGQ = 10)`, but I honestly do not understand the formula argument very well - I'm being tasked with this because I'm the programmer on the project, but my background with statistics... well, it's something that I want to work on.

I've tried looking into brms as well, but it looks even more arcane. The models I tried with that library are:

```
model <- brm(Result ~ Coin, family = bernoulli, data = d)
model2 <- brm(Result ~ Coin, family = binomial, data = d)
```

I also wanted to try a model that allows the variances of the coins to be unequal (or, at least, that is a characteristic of this model according to this source: https://vuorre.netlify.com/post/2017/01/02/how-to-compare-two-groups-with-robust-bayesian-estimation-using-r-stan-and-brms/):

```
uneq_var_frm <- bf(Result ~ Coin, sigma ~ Coin, nl=TRUE)
mod_uneqvar <- brm(
  uneq_var_frm, family = binomial,
  data = d)
```

However, this throws the error "Error: The parameter 'sigma' is not a valid distributional or non-linear parameter. Did you forget to set 'nl = TRUE'?"

In any case, what comes out of all these models is over my head. Even if any of these models are correct (which is quite a leap of faith for me to think that I'm doing it right thus far) I do not know how to use them to give me the information I need. Can anyone share some guidance on this?

Comment: You state your goal in a confusing way. I am guessing that you want to test the null hypothesis that  each of the 3 coins have the same probability of getting heads.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I'm always skeptical of 'perfect analogies'. If you are trying to detect the difference between $p=.73$ and $p=.80$ with $n = 100$ tosses per coin, you have very low probability of doing that. Perhaps you'd be able to detect that difference with $n = 500.$ // A chi-sq test with your synthetic data on 3 coins gives a P-value $\approx 0.5 >> 0.05.$ // In a public opinion poll (where p is about 1/2), it takes 2500 responses to distinguish 50% in favor from 52% in favor. // What are actual percentages of heads and actual numbers of tosses of each coin?

Comment: The actual 'coins' are vials of flies; the heads and tails are the phenotypes of the flies. There are a total of over 1000. Each vial contained the same experiment. Outcome percentages in the vials range from 70% to100% of the flies being of type a, and 0% to 30% of flies being type b. We want to make certain that the conditions that varied from vial to vial (e.g. minor differences in the fly food, temperature variation, etc) did not impact the final rates in the vials.